# Solving $z^4 + 4i\bar{z} = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

How to solve $z^4 + 4i\bar{z} = 0$ (efficiently)?

I managed to compute the radius of $z$:

Denote $z = rcis(\theta)$

Rearranged the equation to $z^4 = -4i\bar{z}$

Taken absolute value on both sides $r^4 = 16r$

And found $r=0$ or $r = \sqrt[3]{16}$

How can we calculate $\theta$ from here?

Or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if $z^4=-4i\overline z$, then $r^4=4r$, and therefore $r=\sqrt[3]4$.

If $r=0$, the $z=0$, which is a solution.

And if $r=\sqrt[3]4$, then, if $z=re^{i\theta}$, we have $z^4=4\sqrt[3]4e^{4i\theta}$ and $-4i\overline z=4ie^{-\pi i/2-i\theta}$. So,$$4\theta=-\frac\pi2-\theta+2k\pi,$$for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $z=0$ is a solution. We can then proceed with the assumption that $z=re^{i\theta}$ is nonzero.

Your equation becomes $r^4e^{4i\theta}+4ire^{-i\theta}=0$ and therefore
$$
r^3e^{5i\theta}=-4i
$$
By uniqueness of the polar representation, you obtain
$$
r^3=4,\qquad e^{5i\theta}=e^{-i\pi/2}
$$
and so
$$
r=\sqrt[3]{4},\qquad \theta=-\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{2k\pi}{5},\ k=1,2,3,4,5
$$
if you want $\theta$ in the $[0,2\pi)$ interval.

Answer (score 0):

By taking the modulus we get $|z|^4=4|z|\iff |z|=0\text{ or }|z|=\sqrt[3]{4}$

Let set aside the trivial solution $z=0$ then by multiplying by $z$ we get

$z^5=-4iz\bar z=-4i|z|^2=-8i\sqrt[3]{2}=-i\,2^\frac{10}{3}$

Therefore $z=\Big(-i\, 2^{\frac 23}\Big)\omega_k\ $ for $\, k=0,1,2,3,4\ $ and $\omega^5=1$ is a fifth root of unity.